Unable to properly strip code comment from snippet
Here is a C++ file, documented using Doxygen-style C-style "banner" comments:
/******************************************************//**
 * @brief An example for Stack Overflow
 * @file main.cpp
 *
 *********************************************************/
//! \noop [mytag]
class Foo
{

public:

    /**************************************************//**
     * @brief Desctructor.
     *
     *****************************************************/
    ~Foo() = default;

    /**************************************************//**
     * @brief Does some stuff
     *
     *****************************************************/
    void DoStuff();

};
//! \noop [mytag]

I'm including this class as a snippet in a Markdown file using the information given here (check out this if you want to understand the use of \noop here). Here is the Markdown file:
Here is the output:

\snippet main.cpp mytag

It has weird comment lines added even if `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` is set to `YES`.

Finally, here is the Doxygen configuration file (everything is located in the same directory, at root level):
INPUT = .
EXAMPLE_PATH = .
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = YES

The output is the following:

Notice the extra /********/ comment lines above each method, even if I specified to remove the comments. I can set JAVADOC_BANNER to YES to specify that /**********/ should be seen as Doxygen comments, but then here is the output:

In this case, the extra comments are removed from the generated snippet, but there are extra newlines inserted between each methods. I would have expected this as the output:
class Foo
{

public:

    ~Foo() = default;

    void DoStuff();

};

If possible, I would like to avoid setting JAVADOC_BANNER to YES because this would make lots of private comments (i.e. same anatomy, but without the extra //**) visible in the generated documentation.
Is there a way to avoid this?
I am using Doxygen v10.0.

Well, there are no EXTRA newlines inserted.  The newlines are not part of the comments, so they remain.

I understand, but this leads either to crowded sources, or unevenly spaced snippets...

Yep.  This is why I changed to the "///" style of comment markers for my C++ code.

It's a bit sad because I was using this banner style to be able to make a comment private simply by removing the // from the top line. With other banner styles this is not possible.
